# Nexus 5 - ADB and Boot problems

Tags: android, nexus-5

I add Paranoid OTA on my Nexus 5, and I tried to uninstall it.

During the processus, everything totally failed and my phone start rebooting itself all the time.

Now :

ADB is not working. (I tried to end and restart the server but nothing to do)
My phone is not recognize on my computer (windows 8.1)
I can't install the driver on my computer

And i CANNOT start my phone, I don't have any more any system on it ...

I'm totally lost and I don't know what to do =/

Comment: Basically it's for developping ^^' 
I was triing to run my app on my phone with android studio

Comment: Android StackExchange may be a better place: http://android.stackexchange.com/ Or the XDA forums

Comment: @daentech okay great thank you, and sorry for posting here :)

Comment: You probably want fastboot to replace an entire system image **such as when developing android itself** - ADB only works once you have a linux kernel and semi-stable system (either normal or recovery) up.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes I want to replace a image (I don't have any image actually on my phone) So how can I do it ?

Comment: Read the docs on fastboot.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisStratton but nothing happened. My phone is still not connected to my computer =/